# How to Log All IRC data on Channel Using Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, logging, irc

I have a somewhat unique request. What I am looking to do is listen on a specific port for all traffic coming through via IRC protocol. I then want to log all of those messages/commands/ect. I do not, however, want to join the channel. I just want to listen and log. Is there an easy built in way to do this? I have been looking at the irc.IRC and irc.IRCClient classes in twisted but they both seem too high level to do this. Is the only way to do this to simply descend to the base Server class, or can I still leverage some of the higher level functionality of twisted?

Comment: If you want to spy on your users, try tcpdump. But tell me the host of your IRCServer so I can make sure I never connect to the network.

Comment: I'm not interested in running an IRC server, it's more at looking at traffic coming over a network in general. And I'm not looking to spy on users, I've been tasked with studying usage through our proxy.

Comment: If it is your machine, any packet dumper (tcpdump/ethereal/...) will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We addressed this issue in a somewhat round about way. We worked off a generic hexdumping proxy server constructed in twisted and then created finer detail parsing algorithms off of that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this if you just connect to a server... the servers don't send you messages for channels you haven't joined.  Or are you the host of the server?

Comment: I'm not the host nor joining the network, I just want to study the traffic overall.